# Meta User link missing on the main site

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

The Meta Link appears to be missing on the main site:

[image]

Also, when using Firefox 60.0.1, I am presented with the scary SSL warning about the connection not being secure.

Is this normal? I've used Stack Exchange for awhile, but am new to the mathematics site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And... five minutes later, the link is back. Tried it out in a different browser, and everything seemed OK. Switched back to Firefox, and found that it was working there, too.

Now that I think about it, [this happened to me on Super User awhile ago, too](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12931/243707).

Comment: Obligatory: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/